# ubuntu 15.10 display blur lines and hang issue with intel core 2 cpu

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 15.10

[image: system specification]

[image: blur screen image]

screen blurs as below. 
after the blur screen sometimes system recovered by window TAB / minimize method but sometimes it freezes after the blur screen and need to restart manually.

I have tried to install updated intel graphics driver but issue still persists.

Comment: can you start a other (Live)-OS without these issues?

Comment: yes i have windows dual boot which is working fine.

Comment: please give us some more details: was the system previously running fine? what have you done (updates? installed other things?) right before you got this lines? -- i'm not familiar with unity but maybe (if it's a problem with 3D-acceleration; and i assume that) you can use a 2D/recovery-mode to still work with your system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below solution worked for me.

If somebody encountered this problem solution that worked for me was to disable SNA hardware acceleration. You can check if it is active running
Code in Terminal:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep SNA
```

To disable SNA you need to create /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder (let it be 20-intel.conf) with next lines:
Code:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

and restart xserver (kill X.org process or reboot or ctrl-alt-Backspace).

**rebooting** worked for me.